# Discord.py specific user can react to message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hello I have a Python Discord bot. I would like to create a command like

`!join @User1 @User2 ...`

Only the users tagged in the command can leave a green or red reaction, the bot creates the reactions automatically. however, the other users are not allowed to respond if they are not mentioned in the command above

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx, *members: discord.Member):
    mentioned_members = ctx.message.mentions
    message = await ctx.send("Möchten Sie sich einschreiben?  / ❌")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("❌")

    for member in mentioned_members:
        await message.add_reaction(member.emoji)

@bot.event 
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.mentions and reaction.user in reaction.message.mentions:
        if reaction.emoji == "":
            await ctx.send(f"{user.name} hat sich eingeschrieben.")         
        elif reaction.emoji == "❌":
            await ctx.send(f"{user.name} hat sich abgemeldet.")     
    else:
        await reaction.remove(user)
```

Comment: Hi, please fix the formatting, it is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this with permissions but you could code it and remove any reactions that don't belong to the users tagged in the message.

There's the [`reaction_remove`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.remove_reaction) method on the `Message` object that you could call when a user reacts to one of those messages and isn't in the message mentions. You can get the message mentions using the [`mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) property on the `Message` object.

Hopefully that's enough to go on - let me know if you want a code example but give it a go yourself first.